# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, errorNum=933, offset=407

Tags: javascript, oracle-sqldeveloper, knex.js, node-oracledb

I am using Knex to create my command. My command is created by this function:

```
static async insertAndReturnId(payload) {
  // getting each property from the payload
  const counts = _.get(payload, 'counts', false)
  let counts_string = '{}'
  if (counts) {
     counts_string = JSON.stringify(counts)
  }
  const content_ids = _.get(payload, 'content_ids', false)
  let content_ids_string = '[]'
  if (content_ids) {
    content_ids_string = JSON.stringify(content_ids)
  }
  const search_query = _.get(payload, 'search_query', false)
  let search_query_string = '{}'
  if (search_query) {
    search_query_string = JSON.stringify(search_query)
  }
  const republishing_reason = _.get(payload, 'republishing_reason', null)
  const job_id = uuid.v4()
  const creation_date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
  const last_modified_date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ')
  const created_by = _.get(payload, 'createdBy', false)
  if (!created_by) {
    throw new Error('created_by is required')
  }
  const last_updated_by = created_by
  const custom_query = `insert into ${this.tableName} (job_id, counts, type, content_ids, search_query, republishing_reason, duration, creation_date, last_update_date, created_by, last_updated_by) values ('${job_id}','${counts_string}', '${payload.type}', '${content_ids_string}', '${search_query_string}', '${republishing_reason}', ${payload.duration}, to_date('${creation_date}','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('${last_modified_date}','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), ${created_by}, ${last_updated_by});`
  try {
    await this.knex().raw(custom_query)
    return job_id
  }
  catch (error) {
    log.error(`Error while inserting mass republish jobs with payload: ${JSON.stringify(payload)}`, error)
    return false
  }
}
```

When I attempted to insert, I kept getting this error:

```
Error: insert into WWT_ATC_API.MASS_REPUBLISH_JOBS (job_id, counts, type, content_ids, search_query, republishing_reason, duration, creation_date, last_update_date, created_by, last_updated_by) values ('adfe4e04-bc82-4954-a68b-38684fda6778','{}', 'manual', '[11111]', '{}', 'string', 0, to_date('2022-06-23 23:51:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2022-06-23 23:51:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 310242, 310242); - ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended, errorNum=933, offset=407
```

However, when I used SQL Developer to run the command:

```
insert into WWT_ATC_API.MASS_REPUBLISH_JOBS (job_id, counts, type, content_ids, search_query, republishing_reason, duration, creation_date, last_update_date, created_by, last_updated_by) values ('adfe4e04-bc82-4954-a68b-38684fda6778','{}', 'manual', '[11111]', '{}', 'string', 0, to_date('2022-06-23 23:51:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), to_date('2022-06-23 23:51:10','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 310242, 310242);
```

It ran through and created a row. What happened here would cause it not able to execute this command? I appreciate any helps!

Comment: Doesn't Knex provide a way to do prepared statements instead of substituting values directly into the SQL string?

Comment: Use `console.log(custom_query)` and make sure all the quoting is correct.

Comment: In your `const custom_query = '...'` line, remove the semicolon from the end of the SQL statement. That is a statement separator, not part of the statement itself.